# Symfony DI calling to static method

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I use this library https://github.com/smsapi/smsapi-php-client to send sms from site. But I had a problem when I try to handle base class in service. So my question is there is the way to call a static method with with argument? I try to do it this by factory but this doesn't work for me. This is my code:

```
smsapi.client:
   class: SMSApi\Client
   factory: ['SMSApi\Client', createFromToken]
   properties:
       attributes: '%smsapi_token%'
```

But I got error below:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for SMSApi\Client::createFromToken(), called in ../cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 5073 and defined
```

Comment: "Does not work for me" is not a meaningful description of the problem. Please provide actual error messages or symptoms. That said, there is no `properties` attribute in service configuration. I think you mean to specify `arguments`. Please refer to the DI docs on the (YAML) syntax of service definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the doc: [Passing Arguments to the Factory Method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html#passing-arguments-to-the-factory-method):

> you can use the `arguments` options inside the service container.

As Example:

```
smsapi.client:
   class: SMSApi\Client
   factory: ['SMSApi\Client', createFromToken]
   arguments:
       attributes: '%smsapi_token%'
```

Hope this help

PS: please share the repo of the library you are using or the main part of the source code in order to handle the situation.